# name 'net_input' is not defined even though it is in global

Tags: python, global

I declared `net_input` as a global variable but still I am getting `NameError: name 'net_input' is not defined`

```
global net_input

noise = net_input.detach().clone()
```

Error line is:

```
net_input_saved = net_input.detach().clone()
```

Error

> NameError: name 'net_input' is not defined

Comment: It you define it somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define variable and then make it global to use in entire program.

```
net_input = "some object"   # assume this is an object and defined somewhere else in your program

global net_input            # make sure that net_input is defined prior 

noise = net_input.detach().clone()
```